# Making arrangements to pay my mothers late property taxes

Tags: taxes, real-estate, property-taxes

I want to pay my mother's taxes for her.  I need to bring them current.  can I make arrangement to pay what is owed or does she have to make arrangements?

Comment: Do you have a power of attorney for your mother?  Is setting one up something you should seriously discuss with her?

Comment: Almost anyone can pay anyone's property taxes.  For instance, if you have a mortgage, often the bank keeps an escrow account and pays the property taxes themselves.  I've paid property taxes for relatives.  On another note, make sure you check to see if she qualifies for any local tax reduction.  My mother wasn't taking the home exemption for older residents (a tax reduction) that she was entitled to, so I went in and did the paperwork.  Saves a lot of money.

Comment: NOTE:  as a side issue, I don't know what the tax consequences would be.  Homeowners can often deduct property tax payments from income taxes, but I'm not sure what happens when someone else pays them.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the government doesn't care who pays the bill, as long as it gets paid. However, you should call the government agency in charge to find out exactly what they want you to do.

Answer (score 3):

It helps if you have the most recent tax bill. That will have all the plat or account numbers you need.

You may find that you can pay them electronically.

If this not a one time only event and if you have power of attorney, you can get the local government to switch the notification/mailings  to you.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to call the tax assessor's office for the county (assuming you are in the US) and ask this question. Without specifying a location there is no way to give you a much more authoritative answer.